# Debian with VPN and firewall blocking web traffic

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, firewall, ufw

I have a VPN (IKEv2) set up on a Debian VM. I'm trying create a kill switch to stop all traffic when the VPN goes down. I've followed the guidance of [this post](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/how-to-make-a-vpn-kill-switch-in-linux-with-ufw/).

It seems to work fairly well (torrent traffic is directed through the VPN and is halted when the VPN goes down), but the firewall is blocking web traffic even when the VPN is up.

Here is my firewall config:

```
sudo ufw reset
sudo ufw allow in from 192.168.0.0/24 
sudo ufw allow out to 192.168.0.0/24 
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw allow out to 184.75.213.194 port 500 proto udp
sudo ufw allow out to 184.75.213.194 port 4500 proto udp
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
sudo ufw allow in on tun0 from any to any
```

Here is some connection info:

```
 > ip addr | grep inet
 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
 inet 192.168.0.30/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
 inet 10.128.1.99/32 scope global enp0s3
 inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe68:3414/64 scope link noprefixroute 
 inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0

> ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
10.128.1.99 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.128.1.99 metric 50 
10.128.1.99 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.128.1.99 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.30 metric 100 

> cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.128.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
search Home

> ip ru
0:  from all lookup local 
220:    from all lookup 220 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 

> resolvectl
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.

> sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.0.0/24            
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere                  

192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
184.75.213.194 500/udp     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
184.75.213.194 4500/udp    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the output of `ip r`, the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`, and maybe also the output of `ip ru` and `resolvectl`, to your question.

Comment: Added all 4. @TomYan

Comment: Also the output of `ufw status`

Comment: @mashuptwice added!

Comment: @furnaceX your default route is over 192.168.0.1 instead of your tunnel. You need to create a default route with your VPNs ip instead to have the traffic routed thru it. Keep in mind that any web traffic like logging in to your gmail account could deanonymize you.

Comment: @mashuptwice If I do a  ```sudo ip route add default via 184.75.213.194```
I get ```Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway```

Comment: @mashuptwice see `ip ru` output @furnaceX so don't mess with the routing (yet), rather you may want to add `ip r show table 220` output too. Anyway, I think the problem might related to DNS. You have `10.128.0.1` and `192.168.0.1` as two of the DNS servers to use, which do not make sense if the traffics to these IPs are routed into the tunnel. (And for reasons you used `/32` as the prefix length for `10.128.1.99`, so no correct / direct route that covers `10.128.0.1` is added anyway. (What's `10.128.1.99` even for? Why two addresses on `enp0s3`?)

Comment: IPSec in common setup rarely uses a separate interface. So tun0 here appears to be for OpenVPN and would then be irrelevant (wrong tutorial...). iptables rules filtering IPSec have to check for IPSec policies and I don't see any here. You should provide your (apparently) StrongSwan configuration. I'm writing iptables instead of UFW because one must know about the backend, and I'm not sure UFW has options to handle IPSec except by adding direct iptables rules, in which case better drop UFW and just use iptables.